# Java music bot not playing music

Tags: java, discord, bots

I'm creating a java music bot. I run into a problem that the bot joins my channel but it does not start playing music. I'm using JDA and lavaplayer to run the bot. It can find the track and even calls the .trackLoaded function in the AudioLoadResultHandler class. I am running java 19 on my windows pc.

My maven dependencies:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>dv8tion</id>
        <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
        <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Discord Bot - JDA-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-beta.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Music library - Lavaplayer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
        <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.78</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Injection - Guice -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My PlayerManager class:

```
public class PlayerManager {

private Map<Long, GuildMusicManager> guildMusicManagers = new HashMap<>();
private AudioPlayerManager audioPlayerManager = new DefaultAudioPlayerManager();

public PlayerManager() {
    registerRemoteSources(audioPlayerManager);
    registerLocalSource(audioPlayerManager);
}

public GuildMusicManager getGuildMusicManager(Guild guild) {
    return guildMusicManagers.computeIfAbsent(guild.getIdLong(), (guildId) -> {
        GuildMusicManager musicManager = new GuildMusicManager(audioPlayerManager, guild);
        guild.getAudioManager().setSendingHandler(musicManager.getAudioForwarder());
        return musicManager;
    });
}

public void play(Guild guild, String trackURL) {
    GuildMusicManager guildMusicManager = getGuildMusicManager(guild);
    audioPlayerManager.loadItemOrdered(guildMusicManager, trackURL, new AudioLoadResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void trackLoaded(AudioTrack audioTrack) {
            guildMusicManager.getTrackScheduler().queue(audioTrack);
        }

        @Override
        public void playlistLoaded(AudioPlaylist audioPlaylist) {
            guildMusicManager.getTrackScheduler().queue(audioPlaylist.getTracks().get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void noMatches() {
            System.out.println("not matches");
        }

        @Override
        public void loadFailed(FriendlyException e) {
            System.out.println("load failed");
        }
    });
}
```

My GuildMusicManager class:

```
@Getter
public class GuildMusicManager {

private TrackScheduler trackScheduler;
private AudioForwarder audioForwarder;

public GuildMusicManager(AudioPlayerManager audioPlayerManager, Guild guild) {
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = audioPlayerManager.createPlayer();
    trackScheduler = new TrackScheduler(audioPlayer, guild);
    audioPlayer.addListener(trackScheduler);
    audioForwarder = new AudioForwarder(audioPlayer);
}
}
```

My TrackScheduler class:

```
@Getter
public class TrackScheduler extends AudioEventAdapter {

private AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
private BlockingQueue<AudioTrack> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private Guild guild;

TrackScheduler(AudioPlayer audioPlayer, Guild guild) {
    this.audioPlayer = audioPlayer;
    this.guild = guild;
}

@Override
public void onTrackStart(AudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track) {
    EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
    builder.setColor(MAGENTA);
    AudioTrackInfo info = track.getInfo();
    builder.setTitle("Jetzt läuft: " + info.title);

    long sekunden = info.length/1000;
    long minuten = sekunden/60;
    long stunden = minuten/60;
    minuten %= 60;
    sekunden %= 60;

    String url = info.uri;
    builder.addField(info.author, "[" + info.title +"](" + url + ")", false);
    builder.addField("Länge", info.isStream ? ":red_circle: Stream" : (stunden > 0 ? stunden + "h " : "") + minuten + "min " + sekunden + "s", true);

    map.get(guild.getIdLong()).sendMessageEmbeds(builder.build()).queue();
}

@Override
public void onTrackEnd(AudioPlayer player, AudioTrack track, AudioTrackEndReason endReason) {
    audioPlayer.startTrack(queue.poll(), false);

    newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
        try {
            sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        if(isNull(player.getPlayingTrack())) {
            if(nonNull(guild.getAudioManager().getConnectedChannel())) {
                guild.getAudioManager().closeAudioConnection();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void queue(AudioTrack audioTrack) {
    if (!audioPlayer.startTrack(audioTrack, true)) {
        queue.offer(audioTrack);
    }
}
}
```

My AudioForwarder class:

```
public class AudioForwarder implements AudioSendHandler {

private final AudioPlayer audioPlayer;
private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = allocate(1024);
private final MutableAudioFrame audioFrame = new MutableAudioFrame();

public AudioForwarder(AudioPlayer audioPlayer) {
    this.audioPlayer = audioPlayer;
    this.audioFrame.setBuffer(byteBuffer);
}

@Override
public boolean canProvide() {
    return audioPlayer.provide(audioFrame);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public ByteBuffer provide20MsAudio() {
    return byteBuffer.flip();
}

@Override
public boolean isOpus() {
    return true;
}
}
```

My Play command:

```
@CommandBase.Command(name = "play", description = "Wähle ein Lied, das abgespielt werden soll.", hasOptions = true)
public class PlayCommand extends CommandBase {

@Inject
private JavaBot javaBot;

public static HashMap<Long, TextChannel> map = new HashMap<>();

public PlayCommand(@NotNull Command command) {
    super(command);
}

@Override
public void execute(Member member, TextChannel textChannel, List<OptionMapping> options, SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
    GuildVoiceState guildVoiceState = member.getVoiceState();

    if (isNull(guildVoiceState) || isNull(guildVoiceState.getChannel()) || isNull(guildVoiceState.getChannel().asVoiceChannel())) {
        event.reply("Du musst in einem Sprachkanal sein.").queue(); //TODO Replace with embed (EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder())
        return;
    }

    VoiceChannel voiceChannel = guildVoiceState.getChannel().asVoiceChannel();
    PlayerManager playerManager = javaBot.getPlayerManager();
    AudioManager manager = voiceChannel.getGuild().getAudioManager();
    manager.openAudioConnection(voiceChannel);

    String url = options.get(0).getAsString();
    if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
        url = "ytsearch:" + url + " audio";
    }
    event.reply("Suche nach dem Titel...").queue(); //TODO Replace with embed (EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder())

    playerManager.play(event.getGuild(), url);
    map.put(voiceChannel.getGuild().getIdLong(), textChannel);
}

@Override
public void autoComplete(String optionName, CommandAutoCompleteInteractionEvent event) {
    List<String> options = of("Achterbahn wise guys", "Ich trink uso was trinkst denn du so", "for the night pop smoke"); //TODO add logic to get famous songs

    if (optionName.equalsIgnoreCase("song")) {
        List<net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.Command.Choice> returnChoices = options.stream()
                .filter(option -> option.toLowerCase().startsWith(event.getFocusedOption().getValue().toLowerCase()))
                .map(option -> new net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.Command.Choice(option, option))
                .collect(toList());
        event.replyChoices(returnChoices).queue();
    }
}

@Override
public List<OptionData> getOptions() {
    return of(new OptionData(STRING, "song", "Titel oder URL vom Lied", true, true));
}
}
```

As you can see from my pom.xml file, I am running the latest version of JDA and Lavaplayer. My bot also has the highest possible permissions on my discord server. The bot also worked a few weeks ago, but without changing anything big, it's not working anymore. As I said, I am running Java 19. Feel free to ask if you need more information.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you use an end of live Java version?

Comment: What do you mean by that? And which version should I use instead?

Comment: https://www.frameworktraining.co.uk/news-insights/java-19-what-and-should-you-take-notice/

Comment: Okay, I understand what's the problem with that. But even if I change my java version to Java 21 for example, the bot still doesn't work.